# Is there any way to clear the page with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page I made, and I want to clear the page when I click a button.

My page looks like this:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script language="Javascript">
  function myFunction() {

  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 Hello World!<br>
 <input type="button" value="clear" onclick="myFunction()">
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to clear?

Comment: `document.body.textContent = ''`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Is that code clear everything include texts, input tags, tables, and so on?

Comment: Yep, everything inside the `<body>` will disappear

Comment: @CertainPerformance Wow you are so smart! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of your function, you can set the body's text to be blank with `document.body.innerHTML= ''`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML